# Update the columns values on condition by selecting other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to update the date column with the earliest date of a particular country. For example in all the rows of Date column of France country i want 16/03/2020 which is the earliest of France. How can I update specific rows value keeping France constant?

```
85  China   23/01/2020
111 France  NaN
112 France  27/03/2020
113 France  NaN
114 France  20/03/2020
115 France  NaN
116 France  NaN
117 France  NaN
118 France  NaN
119 France  NaN
120 France  16/03/2020
139 Iran    15/03/2020
143 Italy   11/03/2020
217 Spain   14/03/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` and `transform` with `min` value:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["Date"] = df.groupby("Country")["Date"].transform("min")

print (df)

     id Country       Date
0    85   China 2020-01-23
1   111  France 2020-03-16
2   112  France 2020-03-16
3   113  France 2020-03-16
4   114  France 2020-03-16
5   115  France 2020-03-16
6   116  France 2020-03-16
7   117  France 2020-03-16
8   118  France 2020-03-16
9   119  France 2020-03-16
10  120  France 2020-03-16
11  139    Iran 2020-03-15
12  143   Italy 2020-03-11
13  217   Spain 2020-03-14
```

Comment: All the rows of Date Coloumn of France should have minimum date. But here diff rows of France have diff dates which are not minimum

Answer (score 0):

```
country_earliest_dt_dct = df.groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x.min())['date'].to_dict()
df['date'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: country_earliest_dt_dct[x])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: Sorry I assumed country and date were columns in your dataframe. See my edits, and replace the indexing (brackets with strings in them) with the name of your columns.

Comment: Please add an explanation with your code sample to improve this answer.